# Reading a File as Strings

Tags: c

I want to read the data of the file into a string.

Is there a function that reads the whole file into a character array? 
I open the file like this:

```
FILE *fp;

for(i = 0; i < filesToRead; i++)
{
  fp = fopen(name, "r");

  // Read into a char array.  
}
```

EDIT: So how to read it "line by line" getchar() ?

Comment: Not unless you write one. You will have to read every file line by line

Comment: Sure, [memmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) the file and then you can access it as an array.

Comment: How to read it line by line? Or do you mean char by char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to read an entire file into a contiguous buffer:

1. Figure out the file length, then `fread()` the whole file.  You can figure out the length with `fseek()` and `ftell()`, or you can use `fstat()` on POSIX systems.  This will not work on sockets or pipes, it only works on regular files.
2. Read the file into a buffer which you dynamically expand as you read data using `fread()`.  Typical implementations start with a "reasonable" buffer size and double it each time space is exhausted.  This works on any kind of file.
3. On POSIX, use `fstat()` to get the file and then `mmap()` to put the entire file in your address space.  This only works on regular files.

Comment: Yeah I plan to use fstat() to allocate the array size before reading. However, actually getting the data from the file is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Mike John  This is _the_ way to read the entire file.  A file may have embedded `\0` bytes, so consider that if you want to use "strings" which are `\0` terminated.  Also consider opening the file in binary: "rb".

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
FILE *fp;
int currentBufferSize;

for(i = 0; i < filesToRead; i++)
{
  fp = fopen(name, "r");
  currentBufferSize = 0;
  while(fp != EOF)
     fgets(filestring[i], BUFFER_SIZE, fp); 

}
```

Of course you would have to make this in a more robust way, checking if your buffer can hold all the data and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like the following: where you read each line, carefully check the result and pass it to a datastructure of your choosing. I have not shown how to properly allocate memory, but you can `malloc` up front and `realloc` when necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FILE_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int file_read_line(FILE *fp, char *buffer)
{
    // Read the line to buffer
    if (fgets(buffer, FILE_BUFFER_SIZE, fp) == NULL)
        return -errno;

    // Check for End of File
    if (feof(fp))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

void file_read(FILE *fp)
{
    int read;
    char buffer[FILE_BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (1) {

        // Clear buffer for next line
        buffer[0] = '\0';

        // Read the next line with the appropriate read function
        read = file_read_line(fp, buffer);

        // file_read_line() returns only negative numbers when an error ocurred
        if (read < 0) {
            print_fatal_error("failed to read line: %s (%u)\n", 
                strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Pass the read line `buffer` to whatever you want

        // End of File reached
        if (read == 0)
            break;
    }

    return;
}
```